# How to add a scrollbars to a tabitem in java?

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, tabitem

I have a method, which creates a TabFolder with two tabs (TabItem) called "Edition" and "Visualisation" inside it, i want to add a scrollbar to the "EditionTab" tab item.

I tried the following method (addScrollbar) to add a scrollbar but it isn't working, any suggestion ? :

```
public static EditionView create(TabFolder mainTabFolder) {
    return new EditionView(mainTabFolder);
}

private EditionView(TabFolder mainTabFolder) {
    checkNotNull(mainTabFolder);
    this.tabfolder = mainTabFolder;
    this.mainComposite = new Composite(tabfolder, SWT.NONE);
    this.addAlternativeControls = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    this.alternativeControls = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    this.deleteAlternativeControls = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    this.gridLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    this.mainComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);
    initOpenBtn();
    addUserIndication();
    initEditionTab();
    addScrollbar();
}

/**
 * Initialization of the editing tab window
 */
private void initEditionTab() {

    this.editionTab = new TabItem(this.tabfolder, SWT.NONE);
    editionTab.setText("Edition");
}

private void addScrollbar() {
     ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(this.tabfolder, SWT.V_SCROLL |
             SWT.H_SCROLL);
     sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
             sc.setExpandVertical(true);
             sc.setContent(mainComposite);
             sc.setMinSize(mainComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
             editionTab.setControl(sc); 
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: mainComposite should have the scrolled composite as its parent not the tab folder.

Comment: How can mainComposite be the parent of scrolled composite when mainComposite is already used as a parent by tabfolder for other methods like this one for example ? :

private void addUserIndication() {
  this.userIndication = new Label(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
  GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING, false, false);
  userIndication.setLayoutData(gridData);
 }

Should i create an other composite for the scrollbar ?

Comment: It can't be both. Use another composite in the scrolled composite.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate composite for the scrolled contents, something like this:

```java
TabItem editionTab = new TabItem(tabfolder, SWT.NONE);
editionTab.setText("Edition");

ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(tabfolder, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);

editionTab.setControl(sc);

Composite scrolledComp = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
scrolledComp.setLayout(new GridLayout());

sc.setContent(scrolledComp);

// TODO add scrolledComp children here before calling computeSize

sc.setMinSize(scrolledComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```